# Pass native query as String to @Query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I've a query which needs to be constructed as String first.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append(....);
query.append(....);
```

I want to pass this query as a native query, like:

```
myTableRepository.insertData(query.toString());
```

So in `MyTableRepository` I can use it like we generally use native queries using `@Query` annotation.

Is it possible?

P.S. - I'm not using `createNative()`, due to some legacy issue, I don't want to use `EntityManager`.

Comment: Well it's certainly *possible* (via a repository extension method), but sort of defeats the whole purpose of abstracting the data access away using a repository

Comment: @crizzis, can you please redirect me to any example. I know its not ideal but I still want to know how its done. Thanks.

Comment: See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories), for example

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible , it will exposes your code to jpql injection attack, and from perspective of DB optimizer it cause bad performance cause it have to create query each time. You can use [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria) query to build safe dynamic query.